# Is any closed set with two elements a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose you have a set $S = \{a,b\}$  that is closed under an associative operation $ * $, is S necessarily a group? I am having great difficulty trying to prove to myself that there exists a unique identity element.

As S is closed by $*$, $ a*a=a$ or exclusively $a*a=b$. So far, my approach is to show that $a*a=a$ is equivalent to $b*b=a$, however I cannot seem to manipulate the equations to force that implication. Would anyone be able to shed some light? Many Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't $a \ast a = a, b \ast b = b, a \ast b = a$ give a counterexample? Here $b \ast a$ can be chosen arbitrary. (maybe I made a mistake)

Comment: Every two element group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ so any group that has a different structure to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a counter example...

Comment: @Miksu Perhaps "any *semi*group": you've just said that there is no group structure on two elements except $\Bbb Z_2$, how can you suggest looking for it?

Comment: @G. Sassatelli I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you clarify? Like how to prove that it's the only group structure with two elements?

Comment: I believe G. Sassatelli means  your reference to "any group ..." when you are then saying it **can't** be a group,  Perhaps "purported group" would have been better.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the general question of $(\{a,b\},*)$ being a group, the answer is no: consider the operation $\max$ on the set $\{0,1\}$. It induces a monoid structure - associative and $0$ is the neutral element - but $1$ has no inverse.

Moreover, any set $S$ with a constant map $c:S\times S\to S$ is certainly a semigroup.

There is a last semigroup operation: $$a*b=b$$
This is neither abelian nor a monoid, and it completes, together with $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z,+)$, $\max$, and the constant, the list of the possible isomorphism classes of semigroups of two elements.